# Determining Time and Space Complexity of program

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

So I had a coding challenge for an internship and part of it was to determine the space and time complexity of my program. The program was roughly as follows.

```
while(A){
  int[][] grid;
  // additional variables

 while(B){ //for loop involves iterating through grid
  // additional variables
  for(...) 
    for(....)
 }

  for(...) //for loop involves iterating through grid
    for(....)
}
```

So what I said was that the program overall has time complexity of (A*N^2+B*N^2), therefore concluding that it has an amortized time of O(N^2).

As for the space complexity, was I supposed to sum the number space used by all variables? Assuming every variable is an int and there is 3 in loop A and two in loop B would the space complexity be (A*24 + B*16)?

Comment: if `while(B)` is within `while(A)`, I don't see how you only have `O(n^2)`

Comment: `AN^2+BN^2` is rather `AN^2+ABN^2`, but if A and B lead to constants not dependent on N, yeah, the whole program is `O(N^2)`.

Comment: From your indentation, it appears that you have *nested* grid iterations.  There's not nearly enough detail here to determine complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid mistakes, I tend to use an approach such that you ***make a side note for each line*** representing how many times it gets executed (to be more accurate, you can include both at its best and its worst case).

Taking into consideration the example, the idea may look as follows:

```
num_exec   
        | while(A){
A       |   int[][] grid;
A       |   additional variables
        |
        |   while(B){ //for loop involves iterating through grid
AB      |     additional variables
ABN^2   |     for(...) 
        |       for(....)
        |   }
        |
AN^2    |  for(...) //for loop involves iterating through grid
        |    for(....)
        | }
```

To estimate your code's **time complexity** a simple summation of those side noted numbers does the thing (as you may have done yourself, though you have obtained slightly different results than mine):

[image]

---

As for your **memory complexity**, your intuition is right for an 8-bit integer. However, if we are talking about primitive datatypes, you can simply think of them as constants. Thus, you should be rather concerned about complex datatypes i.e. an array, since it aggregates multiple primitives. To sum up, you take into account data sizes of elements designated to preserve your data.

Consequently, applied on the example:

```
memory   
        | while(A){
ANk     |   int[][] grid;
A3k     |   additional variables
        |
        |   while(B){ //for loop involves iterating through grid
AB2k    |     additional variables
        |     for(...) 
        |       for(....)
        |   }
        |
        |  for(...) //for loop involves iterating through grid
        |    for(....)
        | }
```

Supposing the `grid` size of [image], a primitive datatype with size of [image] and the total number of *additional variables* to be **3** in the outer loop followed by **2** in the inner one, the total space complexity adds up to:

[image]

---

**Note, to assume the complexities given above  [image] and [image] have to be both *significantly less* than [image] and *independent of it* at all.**

You may be interested in further explanation of the matter provided on this [**link**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWL7AZ1kxrE). Hope that helps (even it is just approximate because of coarser details you've provided)  and best of luck!

Comment: Side not approach is an excellent idea. I've never seen that.